# Jqgrid colNames set from a jsp hidden variable

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid whose column Name I wish to set from a jsp hidden variable.

```
<input type="hidden" name="columns" id="columns" value= "<%= finalColumns %>"></input>
```

This hidden id columns has the values:

```
value="'Master Code','Mst. Code Description','Master Code Status','Master Code Groups','Detail Code Groups','No. of Detail Codes','Length','Attribute Type','sample'" .
```

Now I am trying in my Javascript like

```
  colNames:'['+$("#columns").val()+']',
```

But I am getting an alert box saying Length of colNames <> colModel.
I have checked, there are 9 col models and 9 values are present in the string. Where am I doing some mistake

**UPDATE**:**SOLUTION** :
I tried using

```
eval(('['+$("#columns").val()+']').toString()).
```

That solved the problem. I have to understand Why this solves the problem

Thanks anyways

Comment: You should not use `eval` because it can *execute code*. Instead of that one should use `$.parseJSON` function to convert JSON string to object.

Comment: But that string comes from a property file, I will defintely try this sir and let you know. Thanks sir asalways :)

Comment: I am getting an UNCAUGHT SYNTAX ERROR:unexpected token error when I use parseJSON. I am trying to debug and will update. Thanks anyways Oleg

Comment: You are welcome! I think that you should change `'` inside of string `$("#columns").val()` to `"`: `'"Master Code","Mst. Code Description","Master Code Status",...'`. Alternatively you can use `$("#columns").val().split(",")`. It seems me more easy.